# Min step size for Y-axis of chart.js library

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have the line chart on some web-page that shows given data. Y-axis labels are calculated by the library, I'm giving only values for the X-axis.
My question is: can I set min-step for the Y-axis? If X-axis values are all the same (for example, [ 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ]), I'll see the scale for the Y-axis as

```
5.8
5.6
5.4
5.2
5
4.8
```

etc...
I understand that I probably can do something with giving Y-axis labels manually, but maybe library already contains this logic?
I use [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) library with [ng-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) as a wrapper for the Angular (5.x).

Comment: Have you checked [stepSize](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size)?

Comment: It's not the solution, since I need to set this option manually and only if all values in the array are equal. Otherwise, if I'll set the stepSize to 1, I'll get the bloody insanity on the y-Axis labels. I need rather minStepSize or something like that. Or some setting that allows only integers, not float numbers.